# Interpolate between two images

Tags: python, image, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to interpolate between two images in Python.

Images are of shapes (188, 188)

[image: Image_1]
[image: Image_2]

I wish to interpolate the image 'in-between' these two images. Say Image_1 is at location z=0 and Image_2 is at location z=2. I want the interpolated image at location z=1.

I believe this answer (MATLAB) contains a similar problem and solution.

[Creating intermediate slices in a 3D MRI volume with MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28667286/creating-intermediate-slices-in-a-3d-mri-volume-with-matlab)

I've tried to convert this code to Python as follows:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interpn
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

# Construct 3D volume from images
#    arr.shape = (2, 182, 182)
arr = np.r_['0,3', image_1, image_2]

slices,rows,cols = arr.shape

# Construct meshgrids
[X,Y,Z] = np.meshgrid(np.arange(cols), np.arange(rows), np.arange(slices));
[X2,Y2,Z2] = np.meshgrid(np.arange(cols), np.arange(rows), np.arange(slices*2));

# Run n-dim interpolation
Vi = interpn([X,Y,Z], arr, np.array([X1,Y1,Z1]).T)
```

However, this produces an error:

```
ValueError: The points in dimension 0 must be strictly ascending
```

I suspect I am not constructing my meshgrid(s) properly but am kind of lost on whether or not this approach is correct.

Any ideas?

---------- Edit -----------

Found some MATLAB code that appears to solve this problem:

[Interpolating Between Two Planes in 3d space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084698/interpolating-between-two-planes-in-3d-space)

I attempted to convert this to Python:

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import distance_transform_edt
from scipy.interpolate import interpn

def ndgrid(*args,**kwargs):
    """
    Same as calling ``meshgrid`` with *indexing* = ``'ij'`` (see
    ``meshgrid`` for documentation).
    """
    kwargs['indexing'] = 'ij'
    return np.meshgrid(*args,**kwargs)

def bwperim(bw, n=4):
    """
    perim = bwperim(bw, n=4)
    Find the perimeter of objects in binary images.
    A pixel is part of an object perimeter if its value is one and there
    is at least one zero-valued pixel in its neighborhood.
    By default the neighborhood of a pixel is 4 nearest pixels, but
    if `n` is set to 8 the 8 nearest pixels will be considered.
    Parameters
    ----------
      bw : A black-and-white image
      n : Connectivity. Must be 4 or 8 (default: 8)
    Returns
    -------
      perim : A boolean image

    From Mahotas: http://nullege.com/codes/search/mahotas.bwperim
    """

    if n not in (4,8):
        raise ValueError('mahotas.bwperim: n must be 4 or 8')
    rows,cols = bw.shape

    # Translate image by one pixel in all directions
    north = np.zeros((rows,cols))
    south = np.zeros((rows,cols))
    west = np.zeros((rows,cols))
    east = np.zeros((rows,cols))

    north[:-1,:] = bw[1:,:]
    south[1:,:]  = bw[:-1,:]
    west[:,:-1]  = bw[:,1:]
    east[:,1:]   = bw[:,:-1]
    idx = (north == bw) & \
          (south == bw) & \
          (west  == bw) & \
          (east  == bw)
    if n == 8:
        north_east = np.zeros((rows, cols))
        north_west = np.zeros((rows, cols))
        south_east = np.zeros((rows, cols))
        south_west = np.zeros((rows, cols))
        north_east[:-1, 1:]   = bw[1:, :-1]
        north_west[:-1, :-1] = bw[1:, 1:]
        south_east[1:, 1:]     = bw[:-1, :-1]
        south_west[1:, :-1]   = bw[:-1, 1:]
        idx &= (north_east == bw) & \
               (south_east == bw) & \
               (south_west == bw) & \
               (north_west == bw)
    return ~idx * bw

def signed_bwdist(im):
    '''
    Find perim and return masked image (signed/reversed)
    '''    
    im = -bwdist(bwperim(im))*np.logical_not(im) + bwdist(bwperim(im))*im
    return im


def bwdist(im):
    '''
    Find distance map of image
    '''
    dist_im = distance_transform_edt(1-im)
    return dist_im


def interp_shape(top, bottom, num):
    if num<0 and round(num) == num:
        print("Error: number of slices to be interpolated must be   integer>0")

    top = signed_bwdist(top)
    bottom = signed_bwdist(bottom)

    r, c = top.shape
    t = num+2

    print("Rows - Cols - Slices")
    print(r, c, t)
    print("")

    # rejoin top, bottom into a single array of shape (2, r, c)
    # MATLAB: cat(3,bottom,top)
    top_and_bottom = np.r_['0,3', top, bottom]
    #top_and_bottom = np.rollaxis(top_and_bottom, 0, 3)

    # create ndgrids 
    x,y,z = np.mgrid[0:r, 0:c, 0:t-1]  # existing data
    x1,y1,z1 = np.mgrid[0:r, 0:c, 0:t] # including new slice

    print("Shape x y z:", x.shape, y.shape, z.shape)
    print("Shape x1 y1 z1:", x1.shape, y1.shape, z1.shape)
    print(top_and_bottom.shape, len(x), len(y), len(z)) 

    # Do interpolation
    out = interpn((x,y,z), top_and_bottom, (x1,y1,z1))

    # MATLAB: out = out(:,:,2:end-1)>=0;
    array_lim = out[-1]-1    
    out[out[:,:,2:out] >= 0] = 1 

    return out
```

I call this as follows:

`new_image = interp_shape(image_1,image_2, 1)`

Im pretty sure this is 80% of the way there but I still get this error when running:

`ValueError: The points in dimension 0 must be strictly ascending`

Again, I am probably not constructing my meshes correctly. I believe `np.mgrid` should produce the same result as MATLABs `ndgrid` though.

Is there a better way to construct the `ndgrid` equivalents?

Answer (score 10):

I figured this out. Or at least a method that produces desirable results.

Based on: [Interpolating Between Two Planes in 3d space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084698/interpolating-between-two-planes-in-3d-space)

```
def signed_bwdist(im):
    '''
    Find perim and return masked image (signed/reversed)
    '''    
    im = -bwdist(bwperim(im))*np.logical_not(im) + bwdist(bwperim(im))*im
    return im

def bwdist(im):
    '''
    Find distance map of image
    '''
    dist_im = distance_transform_edt(1-im)
    return dist_im

def interp_shape(top, bottom, precision):
    '''
    Interpolate between two contours

    Input: top 
            [X,Y] - Image of top contour (mask)
           bottom
            [X,Y] - Image of bottom contour (mask)
           precision
             float  - % between the images to interpolate 
                Ex: num=0.5 - Interpolate the middle image between top and bottom image
    Output: out
            [X,Y] - Interpolated image at num (%) between top and bottom

    '''
    if precision>2:
        print("Error: Precision must be between 0 and 1 (float)")

    top = signed_bwdist(top)
    bottom = signed_bwdist(bottom)

    # row,cols definition
    r, c = top.shape

    # Reverse % indexing
    precision = 1+precision

    # rejoin top, bottom into a single array of shape (2, r, c)
    top_and_bottom = np.stack((top, bottom))

    # create ndgrids 
    points = (np.r_[0, 2], np.arange(r), np.arange(c))
    xi = np.rollaxis(np.mgrid[:r, :c], 0, 3).reshape((r**2, 2))
    xi = np.c_[np.full((r**2),precision), xi]

    # Interpolate for new plane
    out = interpn(points, top_and_bottom, xi)
    out = out.reshape((r, c))

    # Threshold distmap to values above 0
    out = out > 0

    return out


# Run interpolation
out = interp_shape(image_1,image_2, 0.5)
```

Example output: 
[image: Example Output]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed for something. Just to note that the definition of bwperim can be found at https://github.com/lforet/CoinVision/blob/master/build/mahotas/mahotas/bwperim.py , and that r**2 should be replaced with r*c as not all images are square.

Comment: Good catch on `r**2`. I've since corrected in my own use but forgot to update answer. 

You may also be able to use `return 0 - (im - scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation(im))` for `bwperim` as an alternative to mahotas method. Works well in my case

Answer (score 3):

I came across a similar problem where I needed to interpolate the shift between frames  where the change did not merely constitute a translation but also changes to the shape itself . I solved this problem by :

- Using **center_of_mass** from **scipy.ndimage.measurements** to calculate the center of the object we want to move in each frame
- Defining a continuous parameter t where t=0 first and t=1 last frame
- Interpolate the motion between two nearest frames (with regard to a specific t value) by shifting the image back/forward via **shift** from **scipy.ndimage.interpolation** and overlaying them.

Here is the code:

```
def inter(images,t):
#input: 
# images: list of arrays/frames ordered according to motion
# t: parameter ranging from 0 to 1 corresponding to first and last frame 
#returns: interpolated image

#direction of movement, assumed to be approx. linear 
a=np.array(center_of_mass(images[0]))
b=np.array(center_of_mass(images[-1]))

#find index of two nearest frames 
arr=np.array([center_of_mass(images[i]) for i in range(len(images))])
v=a+t*(b-a) #convert t into vector 
idx1 = (np.linalg.norm((arr - v),axis=1)).argmin()
arr[idx1]=np.array([0,0]) #this is sloppy, should be changed if relevant values are near [0,0]
idx2 = (np.linalg.norm((arr - v),axis=1)).argmin()

if idx1>idx2:
    b=np.array(center_of_mass(images[idx1])) #center of mass of nearest contour
    a=np.array(center_of_mass(images[idx2])) #center of mass of second nearest contour
    tstar=np.linalg.norm(v-a)/np.linalg.norm(b-a) #define parameter ranging from 0 to 1 for interpolation between two nearest frames
    im1_shift=shift(images[idx2],(b-a)*tstar) #shift frame 1
    im2_shift=shift(images[idx1],-(b-a)*(1-tstar)) #shift frame 2
    return im1_shift+im2_shift #return average

if idx1<idx2:
    b=np.array(center_of_mass(images[idx2]))
    a=np.array(center_of_mass(images[idx1]))
    tstar=np.linalg.norm(v-a)/np.linalg.norm(b-a)
    im1_shift=shift(images[idx2],-(b-a)*(1-tstar))
    im2_shift=shift(images[idx1],(b-a)*(tstar))
    return im1_shift+im2_shift
```

[Result example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pXp1.png)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the solution to your problem, but I don't think it's possible to do this with `interpn`.

I corrected the code that you tried, and used the following input images:

[image: img1][image: img2]

But the result is:

[image: result]

Here's the corrected code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from scipy import interpolate

n = 8
img1 = np.zeros((n, n))
img2 = np.zeros((n, n))

img1[2:4, 2:4] = 1
img2[4:6, 4:6] = 1

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img1, cmap=cm.Greys)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img2, cmap=cm.Greys)

points = (np.r_[0, 2], np.arange(n), np.arange(n))
values = np.stack((img1, img2))
xi = np.rollaxis(np.mgrid[:n, :n], 0, 3).reshape((n**2, 2))
xi = np.c_[np.ones(n**2), xi]

values_x = interpolate.interpn(points, values, xi, method='linear')
values_x = values_x.reshape((n, n))
print(values_x)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(values_x, cmap=cm.Greys)
plt.clim((0, 1))

plt.show()
```

I think the main difference between your code and mine is in the specification of `xi`. `interpn` tends to be somewhat confusing to use, and I've explained it in greater detail in an [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39357219/525169). If you're curious about the mechanics of how I've specified `xi`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27286794/525169) of mine explaining what I've done.

This result is not entirely surprising, because `interpn` just linearly interpolated between the two images: so the parts which had 1 in one image and 0 in the other simply became 0.5.

Over here, since one image is the translation of the other, it's clear that we want an image that's translated "in-between". But how would `interpn` interpolate two general images? If you had one small circle and one big circle, is it in any way clear that there should be a circle of intermediate size "between" them? What about interpolating between a dog and a cat? Or a dog and a building?

I think you are essentially trying to "draw lines" connecting the edges of the two images and then trying to figure out the image in between. This is similar to sampling a moving video at a half-frame. You might want to check out something like [optical flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow), which connects adjacent frames using vectors. I'm not aware if and what python packages/implementations are available though.

Comment: Interesting insight, I now understand interpn a lot better. I actually achieved the same results as you using `ndimage.map_coordinates` with 0.5 value sampling from each image (which makes perfect sense now that I think about it).

Comment: I have some other ideas for this problem. It might be possible to construct a 3D geometry using `marching_cubes` then re-sample the verts & faces to get the plane that I need. Or it looks like ITK provides a suitable solution built in https://github.com/KitwareMedical/ITKMorphologicalContourInterpolation

Comment: You could probably get a similar but a lot easier to code result just using `skimage.transform.resize`. I mean the image space interpolation, if you want contour interpolation ITK looks promising.